# Fetch the total number of rows displayed in all pages

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

The scenario is: In bseindia.com in gainers page I need to get  the count of total number of rows present in all the pages. and write them in excel sheet for 5th, 10th, likewise.

```java
List<WebElement> allrows= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tr[@class='ng-scope']"));
int si=allrows.size();
System.out.println("Number of rows:"+si);

for(int i=0; i<si; i++) {
    WebElement option=allrows.get(i);
    String te=option.getText();
    System.out.println(te);     
}

data = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 4; i < allrows.size(); i += 5) {
    WebElement row = allrows.get(i);
    List<WebElement> cells = row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
    String value = cells.get(0).getText(); 
    data.add(value);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can parse this?
https://api.bseindia.com/BseIndiaAPI/api/MktRGainerLoserData/w?GLtype=gainer&IndxGrp=AllMkt&IndxGrpval=AllMkt&orderby=all
Note : Check if the website allows web crawlers to scrape data.